# Magento redirect from HTML Block

Tags: html, magento, redirect, block

Im want to redirect in my custom html block to specific urls.

What i'm trying:

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_World extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
function __construct()
{
    $i = 0;
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('page/html/world.phtml');
    $this->setCookie();
}

public function setCookie()
{
    $lang = $this->getLanguageCode();
    if(isset($_GET['country'])) {
        $country = $_GET['country']; 
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set('country', $country);
    } else {
        $country = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('country');
    }
    /*Redirect to cookie url*/
    if($country) {
        try {
            $url = "http://myurl.dev/".$country."/";
            Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Because i use a multistore configuration in my .htaccess i use:

SetEnvIf Host www.myurl.dev MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host www.myurl.dev MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^myurl.dev MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host ^myurl.dev MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www.myurl1.dev MAGE_RUN_CODE=vs
SetEnvIf Host www.myurl1.dev MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^myurl1.dev MAGE_RUN_CODE=vs
SetEnvIf Host ^myurl1.dev MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

The Issue:
With this redirect i get the Error 310: Too many redirects.
I can't figure out how to fix this.

Comment: try to explain why you are doing this then others can suggest how to do this and maybe understand why you are failing

Comment: This logic should be in a controller, not in a block.

Comment: Why i'm dooing this: I have a landingpage, where users can choose their language. The language code gets stored in a cookie and the user gets redirected to the right store if he enters the base url again. The html block gets loaded in my custom template file by getChildHtml('world').

I solved this problem with a little javascript in my phtml file, but if s.o. knows a solution to do this in this html block, i would apprechiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too many redirect suggests an infinite loop. It sounds like you are loading this block on every page - which means even once the user is redirected, the block is loaded again and still trys to redirect them.

I would suggest your check for country needs to be changed:

```
if($country) {
```

this check needs to fail once the user has been redirected, to avoid another redirect being sent, currently it looks like it's returning true even after the redirect.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.
I now check if(currentUrl == baseURL){} and now it works.

Answer (score 4):

This is an inappropriate approach given the framework architecture. There are several mechanisms available for you as a developer to have your code parsed and trigger a redirect. Your current approach has you using the View layer to trigger a redirect, when the request Controller layer and event-observer system would be much more appropriate.

The `controller_action_predispatch` event is one which is available on all request scopes, and there are targeted predispatch events for every route. You can use these and the `Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http` object ("the request object") to trigger the redirect.